# Linear Programming in 'scipy.linprog' with non-standard functions

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I am trying to learn about implementation of linear programming (LP) problems in `scipy.linprog`. I understand how it works with basic functions, for example:

```
max 2x+3y
st. 2x-y <= 0
    5x+y >= -10
```

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
c = [-2, -3]
A = [[2, -1], [-5, -1]]
b = [0, 10]
```

Now, when it comes to more complex cases, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811067/scipy-optimize-linprog-with-more-complex-function) there are quite a few things I don't understand.

First, I don't understand how and why `Minimize 1*abs(x_0) + 1*abs(x_1) + ... + 1*abs(x_n))` is changed to `Minimize 1*y_0 + 1*y_1 + ... + 1*y_n` by adding the following constraint `-y_i <= x_i <= y_i  // for i in n`. **EDIT: I understand now that `y_i` is a slack variable, which also is the reason that the A_aux matrix is added. But I don't understand that shape of the Matrix.**

Second, here they use the constraint to `c = np.hstack((np.zeros(N), np.ones(N_AUX)))`. In my example above, there are two variables, which gives a list of the length 2. But here there are N variables, but `c` is a list of N*2? In my example it is easy to understand the values, but here they are `[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]` and I don't see any hint in the function to why these values are chosen.

Third, I understand the A_orig matrix.

```
A_orig = [[0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # orig constraint 1
          [0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # orig constraint 2
          [-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # more interesting problem
          [0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]  # ""   ""          ""
```

Each row simply represents the number of `x_i` and `y_i` `for i in range(1,6)` for every constraint.

But then a second matrix A_aux is added:

```
A_aux = [[-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1]]
```

Which is a skew-symmetric matrix. And I have no idea and can't find any information about why this is added. I don't understand why it is 10*10 either.

Finally, bounds are added. `bnds = [(0, 50) for i in range(N)] + [(None, None) for i in range(N_AUX)] # some custom bounds`.
Here I find it strange that they set (0,50) for the first 5 rows, and then no bounds for the last 5 rows. I don't see any indication to why it should be bounded by 50?

There are quite a lot of questions here. But if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: "non-standard" is blurry here. This all looks pretty standard to me

Comment: I see. Didn't now what to label it as, probably it is just "non-standard" to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a math question than a programming question. Anyway, to answer your other questions:

> In my example above, there are two variables, which gives a list of the length 2. But here there are N variables, but c is a list of N*2?

You need to introduce an additional variable y_i for each abs(x_i). You have N terms abs(x_i), therefore you'll have N+N = 2*N variables after linearizing/reformulating all the absolute values. Each variable x doesn't occurs in the objective in the reformulation, therefore each coefficient of x_i is zero in the objective. And obviously, each one of y_i is 1.

> Which is a skew-symmetric matrix. And I have no idea and can't find any information about why this is added.

You need the matrix A_aux to model the constraints -y_i <= x_i <= y_i. Both y_i and x_i are optimization variables, so you can't pass this constraints as variable bounds. This only works if the bounds are given constants like -1 <= x_i = 2.

Let's say you have the constraints -y_1 <= x_1 <= y_1 and -y_2 <= x_2 <= y_2. This is the same as:

```
-x_1 - y_1 <= 0
 x_1 - y_1 <= 0
-x_2 - y_2 <= 0
 x_2 - y_2 <= 0
```

Adding the hidden zeros, this is the same as

```
-1*x_1 + 0*x_2 - 1*y_1 + 0*y_2 <= 0
 1*x_1 + 0*x_2 - 1*y_1 + 0*y_2 <= 0
 0*x_1 - 1*x_2 + 0*y_1 - 1*y_2 <= 0
 0*x_0 + 1*x_2 + 0*y_1 - 1*y_2 <= 0
```

Can you see it now? It's just a simply matrix vector product:

```
(-1  0  -1   0 ) (x_1) <= 0
( 1  0  -1   0 ) (x_2) <= 0
( 0 -1   0  -1 ) (y_1) <= 0
( 0  1   0  -1 ) (y_2) <= 0
```

Here, the left matrix is just A_aux. If you change the row order, you'll get exactly the same matrix as in your linked answer.

> Finally, bounds are added. bnds = [(0, 50) for i in range(N)] + [(None, None) for i in range(N_AUX)] # some custom bounds. Here I find it strange that they set (0,50) for the first 5 rows, and then no bounds for the last 5 rows. I don't see any indication to why it should be bounded by 50?

The first N variables (x) are non-negative after the reformulation.  The N addition variables y are unbounded, i.e. can be negative or positive, there there are no bounds. However, there's no real need to bound the x variables with 50 from above. It's only meant to be a sharper bound of the optimization variables based on the right-hand side of the other linear constraints in the example.

PS: I can second Sascha's comment in your linked answer, that you should prefer a library like cvxpy if you don't want to do all these transformations/reformulations on your own.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to understand the logic behind A_aux by following your example. I fail to understand "Both y_i and x_i are optimization variables, so you can't pass this constraints as variable bounds".  Even if x_i is replaced by y_i in the objective function, it is still considered a optimization variable, why is that?
Also, why is: "The first N variables (x) are non-negative after the reformulation". For example if `x_1=-5`, `y_1=6`, -> `-y_1=-6` it doesn't violate the constraint?

Comment: The x_i are still optimization variables because you have the constraints -y_i <= x_i <= y_i. You don't know the values of each x_i and y_i, hence both are optimization variables.

Comment: I see. While I have your attention, could I ask you about an unrelated problem, still having a hard time to tranform this knowledge to another issue. I know this might be a lot to ask but I would greatly appreciate it and I have a lot of pressure solving this problem.

Comment: Sure. But I'd recommend to post it on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) instead in case it's no programming question. :)

Comment: This is kind of both. A problem to be implemented in scipy.linprog. It has the following constraints: `https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?\sum%20A_{t}%20\times%20p_{t}\\L_{0}=\\L_{t}=L_{t-1}+A_{t-1};%20t%200\\-1\leq%20A_{t}%20\leq1\\%200\leq%20L_{t}\leq3` and it kind of confuses me since it has an initial level `L_0`. The second constraint also confuses me since it involves the `t-1`. The last two constraints I am pretty sure needs to be converted to `A_t <= 1`,  `-A_t <=1`,  `L_t <= 3`,  `-L_t <=0`. `p_t` is a array of n=120 forecasted prices.

Comment: I have posted this under the math forum instead. Thanks for your help.